# Common function different return types

Tags: typescript

```
class Parent {
  protected data: any;

  get(): dataA | dataB {
    return this.data;
  }
}

class A extends Parent {
  protected data: dataA = getDataA();
}

class B extends Parent {
  protected data: dataB = getDataB();
}
```

What's the proper way to make `a.get()` and `b.get()` return the respective `dataA` and `dataB` types, instead of what is currently `dataA | dataB`, having `a` and `b` being instances of `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a type parameter to `Parent` that allows derived classes to decide the type of the data:

```
class Parent<T> {
    protected data: T;

    get(): T {
        return this.data;
    }
}
class A extends Parent<dataA> {
    protected data: dataA = getDataA();
}

class B extends Parent<dataB> {
    protected data: dataB = getDataB();
}

let a = new A();
var da = a.get(); // is dataA

let b = new B();
var db = b.get();// is dataB
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20dataA%20%7B%20private%20s%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20dataB%20%7B%20private%20s%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getDataA()%3A%20dataA%20%7B%20return%20new%20dataA()%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20getDataB()%3A%20dataB%20%7B%20return%20new%20dataB()%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Parent%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20data%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09get()%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this.data%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20Parent%3CdataA%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20data%3A%20dataA%20%3D%20getDataA()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20Parent%3CdataB%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20data%3A%20dataB%20%3D%20getDataB()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Avar%20da%20%3D%20a.get()%3B%20%2F%2F%20is%20dataA%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0D%0Avar%20db%20%3D%20b.get()%3B%2F%2F%20is%20dataB)

If `dataA` and `dataB` have members in common that yo wish to use in `Parent` you can add a type constraint to `T`. This requires the passed type parameter to have a certain shape, and you can use the members inside `Parent`:

```
class Parent<T extends { commonField: string } > { ... }
```

Comment: Amazing and simple, sucks when you just don't know how to search for it..